# Running crystal reports from csharp.net

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I've created a bunch of RPT files and we've been using Business Objects to run them against our SQL database using a different param's for each `.rpt` file to generate a PDF file.

Is there an APIi I can use to run these reports?

I've downloaded and installed crystal reports for visual studio, but:

1. I'm not sure which dll's I need to add to accomplish this and
2. I can't find any documentation or sample code

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish, your question is not very clear. If you are looking for a program to view the reports in, SAP has a free version of the Crystal Reports Viewer available [here](http://www.sap.com/solution/sme/software/analytics/crystal-reports-viewer/index.html). If you want to create applications to run your reports in, you will need something like Visual Studio, which lets you create Windows Forms or Web Applications to embed your Crystal Reports in.

EDIT: To add Crystal Reports to Visual Studio you will first need to download the runtime from SAP. Most commom runtimes can be found [here](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824). Then you will have to add the CR to your toolbox in VS by choosing Tools -> choose Toolbox items. Make sure the .NET Frameworks Components tab is selected and scroll to the CrystalReport items. Check the items you want to add (CrystalReportViewer for sure) and click OK. After that the CR Viewer should be available to you in the Reporting section of your toolbox.

Comment: I'm trying to create a web page where I can easily run reports from.  I have visual studio, but I can't find the sdk library or documentation for how to run my rpt file with params.

Comment: With VS you will have to install the CR for VS runtime. Then you add the CrystalReportViewer to your toolbox so you can use it in web pages.

Comment: My issue is that I don't want to use their controller.  I'd like to create my own custom controller (or other interface) that runs reports.

Comment: This is the link to the SDK library for VS2010: http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-27465

Comment: Not really, I would have to do a search.